# Highlighting when a value is the same for at least 3 consecutive days (represented by either date or YDAY)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with many individuals over multiple years where I have the total distance an individual ID has moved per day. I am trying to find the julian days that an individual moved less than 200m per day for at least three days in a row.

the data looks similar to below:

```
library(dplyr)
sum_dist<-c(1405,2846,1904,506,400,80,45,57,80,150,199,250,700,
            1105,1846,1004,506,80,65,45,257,80,150,199,259,700)## daily movement in m
ID<-rep(c("AXG12","BVC45"),each=13) ##unique ID 
YDAY<-c(120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,
        123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135)
df<-data.frame(ID=ID,sum_dist=sum_dist,YDAY=YDAY)
df<-df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(low_move=ifelse(sum_dist<=200,1,0)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(ID,YDAY)
```

I have added a column that either has a 0 (the individual has moved more than 200 m within that day) or a 1 (the individual moved less than 200 m in that day). Essentially I would love to add another column that will indicate when there are at least three days where movement is below 200 m (I am thinking similar to above if three consecutive days are <200m than 1 if not than 0 but am open to suggestions on how to do this).

I would LOVE a dplyr solution as I would be grouping by ID and Year (in overall dataset) to get the YDAY values (referring to julians day) for each time that an individual has less than 200m of movement over three consecutive days.

I have tried both of the following:

```
#create a column for the sum of the column before and after- columns that are >=3 represent at
#least three consecutive days of low movement

TrialSE<-df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(prev_move=lag(low_move),
         next_move=lead(low_move)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sum_move=sum(c_across(c(4:6)))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

With this the issue is that I am missing instances with <200m of movement (for example for ID=AXG12 on YDAY=130) that SHOULD be the fourth consecutive day of low movement (in which I want anything >=3 consecutive days to be captured) because the day after is greater than 200 m of daily movement. I have also tried the following suggested on a different post but it also doesnt get me exactly what I want:

```
TrialSE<-df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(rep(rle(low_move)$length>=3,rle(low_move)$length))
```

For this one my issues are 1. I would like to keep the entire dataset instead of just filtering times where three or more are the same, and 2. it puts in YDAY 131 for ID= BVC45 skipping YDAY 130 which is because I am assuming it is just looking for instances where the values are the same but perhaps I am misunderstanding what this is actually doing.

Thanks in advance for any help!

BONUS: I have completed the dates within my overall dataframe, in that if I have an ID that was missing a day, that day was filled with an NA. In instances that I have four rows in a row with <200m of movement but it is split by an NA (missing day) then I would like to assume that the movement from the missing day would have also been <200m, but if the NA is the first or last value for that individual (i.e. values for movement are NA, 150, 160, 210) I would not assume that this missing day was below 200 m (alternatively the NA cannot be the first or last day considered in looking for consecutive days below 200m).

NOTES: some individuals in my full dataset will have more than one instance of these low movement rates, and I would love to evaluate both.